# Edit files stored on server through Office 365

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web application where users upload lots of files on different resources. The users will now have to download the file, edit it, delete the old file in the app then upload the new one. Many of the users already have Office 365, so my question is:
When the users are authenticated through the Office 365 API, is there any posibilty that they can edit the files stored on the server directly, e.g Word and Excel files?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to allow for users to view and edit Office files through a custom web application by deploying Office Web Apps server on a dedicated server or virtual machine. Please have a look at the documentation via this link to learn more on Office Web Apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/office-web-apps-server.

To modify a word or excel document via an API call, you may use Office Add-Ins SDK to build a web application that interacts with the object models in Office applications. Please have a look at the Office Add-Ins SDK documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview?view=excel-js-preview